# How many operator overloads do we need for the following?

Tags: c++

If I make a class Str which operates exactly like C++ strings, and I want to have the following functionality, by overloading the +operator where a,b,c are Str classes:

`Str d = a + b;`, `Str d = "test" + b`, `Str d = b + "test"`, `Str d = c + b`, `Str d = "test" + "test1"`

How many operator+ overloads do I need?

I think I only need 3? Two inside the class for the first four cases (one with an arg accepting a string, another accepting a Str class), and one outside for two strings?

Comment: One if you don't care about extra constructor calls.

Comment: You only need one , a non-member. However `Str d = "test" + "test1"` is not possible because the expression `"test" + "test1"` doesn't know anything about `Str`. You could define a literal suffix.